# Ubuntu 16.04 with micro internet outages

Tags: 16.04, networking, internet

I have recently started to notice frequent irregular micro internet outages. I ran a quick experiment to confirm my suspicion.

I ran two short scripts. One from my Ubuntu machine and one on a Windows laptop on a different network entirely. My Ubuntu machine pinged 1.1.1.1 every second with a timeout of 1 second while the windows machine pinged my Ubuntu networks router. I compared the results and noticed that the Ubuntu ping failed 2-4 times in a row every minute or so. The windows script meanwhile had one lost packets every few minutes or so but they didn't match the Ubuntu machine outages.

Now, I have no clue of where to begin trouble-shooting this within Ubuntu and I can't find anything similar to my issue through google.

Comment: Is the Ubuntu box using WiFi?

Comment: No. but I belive there is a wifi mini card on the mobo. not sure what connection it is. but it's like in the center of the board and maybe a square inch large. It should be disabled.